# CSS tiled, nested div multi-row centering alignment issue

Tags: html, css, angularjs

After having reviewed several existing questions, and attempting countless combinations, I cannot find a solution that addresses this particular centering issue.

I have an outer div that contains a variable number of divs within (using AngularJS).  I have several on a row, but on the next row if it contains less divs than a full row, I need those divs centered.  (Extending the example below, if there were two boxes on the second row, those two boxes together should be centered on the three boxes above.)

This image illustrates the issue:

[image: CSS Tile Div Multi-Row Centering Issue Illustration]

My current code is here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ljbrown238/8pj7cu3e/)

The CSS:

```css
.outerbox {
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.box {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: 2px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

... and the related HTML:

```
    <div ng-if="show" class="outerbox" ng-repeat="box in boxes">
        <div class="box">{{box.name}}</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/uo4pqukr/)

1. Get rid of `float` in `.box`
2. Wrap `.outer-box` inside an `.outerbox-container`:

   ```
    <div class="outerbox-container">
        <div ng-if="show" class="outerbox" ng-repeat="box in boxes">
            <div class="box">{{box.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
   ```
3. Change the css accordingly:

   ```
   .outer-box {
       display: inline-block;
       width: 100px; //instead of 350px
   }

   .outerbox-container {
       width: 350px;
       text-align: center;
   }
   ```

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you so much for the complete solution!

Answer (score 1):

try this way.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.boxes = [
  {name: 'Name 1'},
  {name: 'Name 2'},
  {name: 'Name 3'},
  {name: 'Name 4'}
 ];
});
```

```css
.outerbox {
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.box {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: 2px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.boxClass{
   margin-left: 108px;
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='myCtrl' ng-init="show=false">
    <button ng-model="show" ng-click="show=!show" ng-bind="show?'Animate Leave':'Animate Enter'">
    </button>

    <div ng-if="show" class="outerbox" ng-repeat="box in boxes">
        <div class="box" ng-class="{'boxClass': $last}" >{{box.name}}</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time to respond!  While this looks similar to the accepted answer, the accepted answer provided a complete and functioning example.  Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of float!

```css
.outerbox {
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.box {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: 2px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div ng-if="show" class="outerbox" ng-repeat="box in boxes">
    <div class="box">{{box.name}}</div>
    <div class="box">{{box.name}}</div>
    <div class="box">{{box.name}}</div>
    <div class="box">{{box.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at the code!  Unfortunately, simply removing the "float" line renders all of the boxes centered, one per line.  Thanks again for taking time to respond.

Comment: Check that your resulting html actually looks like what's in my answer. I expect you're repeating the outerbox with one box inside instead of repeating the box within one outerbox

Comment: Steve, the code you provided above does not produce the desired result.  Using the ng-repeat directive, you wouldn't want to repeat the actual 
`<div class="box">{{box.name}}</div>`.  Either way, using this did not provide the expected result.  If you put the raw html manually, your code would be correct, but the solution requires an AngularJS component.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You will need javascript to do this, because as far as I know, css can't count the number of total divs in a row, it can only see `:first-child` `nth-child` and `last child`.

This means css doesn't know how many divs are in the bottom row, so you wouldn't be able to make css code for it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to think about this.  While there ultimately is a CSS trick, as seen in the accepted answer, you make an excellent point that I will stash away for the future.  It is bound to come in handy!